# One or more APIs that are required for game services to work have been turned off in the API console

Tags: unity-game-engine

I had implemented leaderboard in google play store console.  But after implementing when I see the play store console it shows:

> One or more APIs that are required for game services to work have been turned off in the API console. We recommend to turn them on again to ensure your game is working properly.

Also the leaderboard not working.

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using?

Comment: same here. i also have "Turn APIs back on" button below. I press it but after page reloading same error presents. It also says that that APIs that are not turned are "Google Play Game Services" and "Google Play Game Management". But in in google API dashboard they are marked as on.

Comment: I just didn't pulish my game services project. Not i did and leaderboard word.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, and when I clicked the Turn APIs button back on, it would show the error again after a page refresh.

I got in contact with Google and they said that a few other developers were experiencing this issue and that they would email me back once they had made progress finding out what's wrong

Now then - because this all happened around the time I was re-linking a project into Google Play Games Services, I thought I had messed something up. Being restless I decided just now to create a new keystore file, and generate a fresh SHA-1 fingerprint. I was able to enter the newly generated code on the API Manager console, under the Credentials tab.

For some reason, it worked; I am now able to sign via Google and access the high-scores page.

Might be worth a try?